# Daterangepicker - force to allow only date on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs, daterangepicker

I need to do this: allow daterangepicker text input only to accept correct dates (example: when you have selected say `13-01-2020` and then you click input and start typing `18` you get `18-01-2020 instead of 1813-01-2020` an ofcourse non numbers are not allowed .... I hope this is clear).

`Js Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/20z5qym9/`

My customized code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="data_u"]').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        oneTap: true,
        minYear: 1901,
        maxYear: 2022,
                                      
        "locale": {
            "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "OK",
            "cancelLabel": "Leave",
            "fromLabel": "From",
            "toLabel": "To",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            //custimizable list od days
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Pn",
                "Wt",
                "Śr",
                "Czw",
                "Pt",
                "So",
                "Nd"
            ],
            //and months
            "monthNames": [
                "Styczeń",
                "Luty",
                "Marzec",
                "Kwiecień",
                "Maj",
                "Czerwiec",
                "Lipiec",
                "Sierpień",
                "Wrzesień",
                "Październik",
                "Listopad",
                "Grudzień"
            ],
            "firstDay": 0
        }
      
      }
      
      , function(start, end, label) {
        //callback when you choose month, but I would need to have callback on every key pressed I guess
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know why but your js fiddle works perfectly as you excepted on my Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: That is odd. I can type other input than date - I updated the fiddle so you could see input type date - this is what I want (preferebly without limitations of this solution - please see answear below).

Answer (score 0):

`<input type='date' />`

This is how I did it for now. Works ok, but it is not perfect (localise setting is controled by browser, that means user, and that means he can have different date format, date picker behavior and so on).

Funny I was unaware, that browsers have this type on input from some time now.